# Setting up paragraphing of subsections using code from memman.pdf results in mysterious compilation error

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, memoir

I was trying to emulate the style of the long table of contents in the memoir manual. Specifically, the effect I want to achieve is to have all subsections names and page numbers in the same paragraph, eliminating the dots. Refer to the image below, which is a screenshot from the memoir manual. [image: An example of the effect I want to achieve, paragraphing of subsections]

Page 171 of the memoir manual includes code to achieve this effect. However, when I try to compile myself, there is always a mysterious error message, even though hitting enter every time this error occurs will still produce a correct document:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

Here is a minimal example that illustrates this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\setupparasubsecs}{%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline
  \renewcommand{\l@subsection}[2]{%
      \def\numberline####1{\textit{####1}~}%
      \leftskip=\cftsubsectionindent
      \rightskip=\@tocrmarg
      \parfillskip=\fill
      \ifhmode ,\ \else\noindent\fi
      \ignorespaces
      {\cftsubsectionfont ##1}~{\cftsubsectionpagefont##2}%
       \let\numberline\oldnumberline\ignorespaces
  }
}
\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\par}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\setupparasubsecs
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Research}
\kant[1-3]
\section{Survey}
\kant[1-3]
\subsection{Methodology}
\kant[1-3]
\subsection{Hypothesis}
\kant[1-3]
\subsection{Results}
\kant[1-3]
\chapter{Discussions}
\section{Survey}
\subsection{Implications \& Consequences}
\kant[1-3]
\subsection{Flaws \& Limitations}
\kant[1-3]
\chapter{Conclusions}
\kant[1-3]
\end{document}
```

I suspect it could be a problem of not ending a paragraph when typesetting the next chapter heading. Meanwhile, there is also some spacing problems before the comma, which unfortunately isn't replicated in the above example.

I am using the latest TeXLive 2012 distribution and compiling with LuaLaTeX, but the problem is also reproducible in pdfLaTeX.

**EDIT:** I looked at memsty.sty and found the actual code contains:

```
\newcommand*{\setupparasubsecs}{%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline
  \renewcommand{\l@subsection}[2]{
    \ifnum\c@tocdepth > 1\relax
      \def\numberline####1{\textit{####1}~}%

      [snip]

      {\cftsubsectionfont ##1}~{\cftsubsectionpagefont##2}%
       \let\numberline\oldnumberline\ignorespaces
    \fi}}

\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\par}}%%% OK
```

It differs from the code in memman.pdf by an additional `\ifnum`. Apparently in a later revision Peter Wilson decides to add this but it is not reflected in the manual itself. However the `\ifnum` does not seem to eliminate the error, or cause some visual changes to the document though.

**EDIT 2**: I tried to compile the memoir manual and it didn't have this error. I guess I probably left out something in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, you need to end the paragraph. One way would be:

```
\newcommand*{\setupparasubsecs}{%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline
  \renewcommand{\l@subsection}[2]{%
      \def\numberline####1{\textit{####1}~}%
      \leftskip=\cftsubsectionindent
      \rightskip=\@tocrmarg
      \parfillskip=\fill
      \ifhmode ,\ \else\noindent\fi
      \ignorespaces
      {\cftsubsectionfont ##1}~{\cftsubsectionpagefont##2}%
       \let\numberline\oldnumberline\ignorespaces
  }
\let\old@l@section\l@section
\def\l@section{\par\old@l@section}
\let\old@l@chapter\l@chapter
\def\l@chapter{\par\old@l@chapter}
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast and accurate. Helpful for people who don't understand LaTeX internals. Thank you.